# Get Clion to add crate to autocomplete/linting

Tags: rust, clion

I am using Clion with the rust plugin. Whenever I add a crate I have found that I need to restart Clion to get the crate's contents added to the autocomplete/linting (yes I am running `cargo update` after adding the crate to `cargo.toml`).

Is there some way to get clion to update it's autocomplete/linting dictionary without restarting? Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

In general when you change the Cargo.toml (or Cargo.lock) CLion needs to update its view of your cargo dependencies and reindex. You can do this manually with the refresh button here:
[image: a picture of the cargo tool window in clion]

Alternatively you can use ctrl+shift+a(assuming linux keybindings) and then search "Refresh Cargo Projects".